# How to dynamically reload file in Visual Studio ?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have include an xml file included in my solution in visual studio. I am adding new nodes in my file at runtime. But when i am recieving this message all the time `The file has been modified out the source editor. Do you want to reload the file?` Is there any solution that I can dynamically reload file in my code instead of showing this message ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, no. But if you dont want to see it, my advice is to close the xml on VS while running the app, and open it when finished. It will save you from a ton of times clicking "yes" on the alert message.